# Token error on getting started tutorial with Node.js and Google Cloud datastore

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, access-token, google-cloud-datastore

I'm building a webapp with google appengine, node.js and socket.io, and I'm currently trying to set up a google compute instance to use the google cloud datastore api following this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_nodejs/). So far, I've completed steps 1 and 2, but when running the downloaded adams.js file locally, I get this:

```
Error: No access or refresh token is set.
```

Stuff I've tried:

- gcloud auth login *(this logs me in google, but doesn't set my token locally)*
- changing the way I'm exporting my DATASTORE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT and DATASTORE_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE values, as strings, plain text, etc.
- logging my credentials on the line before the error (I'm definitely missing a token)
- creating a new service account and going through key creation steps again
- ran 
  curl "http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token" -D "Metadata-Flavor: Google" to get more info.

that command gives me this:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

so I'm definitely missing a token, but for some reason I cannot figure out how I am supposed to be getting it. Or where I need to store it when my app is deployed and wants to access the API online. It feels like this should be a really easy thing to find, but for some reason all the documentation I'm reading is leading me into walls. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Can you SSH into your Compute Engine instance and try running:

curl "http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/scopes"
 -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"

(that's with an "-H" instead of "-D")

Comment: Sure, that gives me this:

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore`
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`

Comment: That's good -- your GCE instance is set up with the right scopes. Because of that, you should not need the environment variables (you can `unset DATASTORE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT` and `unset DATASTORE_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE`). What's the command you're using to run the adams.js demo on your GCE instance, and what error do you get back?

Comment: @EdDavisson Wow, that just explained my problem, thank you! I thought I was meant to run this code locally- not from the GCE instance. That fixed a huge hangup for me. It's working now.

Comment: Glad it helped! I summarized this in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code is running on a Google Compute Instance, and the instance has the correct scopes, you don't need to set any environment variables.

You can confirm the scopes by looking at the instance in the Developers Console or by asking the metadata server:

```
curl http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/scopes -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

To use Cloud Datastore, both the `datastore` and `userinfo.email` scopes must be present.